# Many to many relation linq query in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables Student, Course, and the linking table StudentCourse, how do i return all the courses given a student Id = 1 but also include row where the student id might not be 1 and is taking same course as student of id 1? The stucture is like this:

```
    student        courses     studentcourse
         1           8            1 -  8
         2           9            2 -  8
         3           10           3 -  9
```

so the tricky part is that i also want to include the other rows for course 8 or any other course taken by Student of id 1.

the final result should be 2 rows: the where clause will specify that I am interested in the course where student id = 1 (which is course of id 8) but i also want to include the other rows from that course. So the result is :

```
1 -  8
2 -  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is EF and your latest clarification you should have a `Courses` navigation property on your `Student` entity and a `Students` navigation on your `Course` entity that would allow you to do the following:

```
var students =  db.Students
                  .Single(x=> x.Id == 1)
                  .Courses.SelectMany(c=> c.Students)
                  .Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi, I think this will not include returning all records for Course 8.
the final result should also incluse student of id 2 because they are also taking course 8

Comment: You want all other rows **just** for course 8? If so that is not possible. Please update your question it looks to me like you want the course given a student id. If not please provide a better example if you could.

Comment: Hi, I did specify the final result should include the other rows that are not of student id 1. That's the challenge I am having cos I got the normal result already but since I am doing a where clause on Id=1,
That's why I am having hard time including the other rows. The scenario is that I get all the records where id = 1 to get the course number then also need to know who else is taking that same course. But dont want to do it in 2 queries. is this possible? a SQL statement would help too.

Comment: It's still not clear - since a student can take many courses do you want to get the rows of all other students that share **any** course with the given student?

Comment: Yes that's what I am after:-)