# How to make a select query on a many to many relation using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Many to many relation linq query in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510297/many-to-many-relation-linq-query-in-ef)

how is it possible to query a many to many relation with linq.
Explanation: i have two tables "conventions" and "participants" with many to many relation the problem is that i can't access the properties of "participants" within the query.

the query:

```
var conv1 =from c in db.Conventions                             
           where c.objet.Contains(s) 
               || c.Domaines.intituleDomaine.Contains(s)
               /* snip */
           select c;
```

and i need to join the other table "participants" and search inside it's properties.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15437/Create-many-to-many-relationships-in-LINQ-for-SQL